# Minimum system requirements for smart contract software development

Tags: docker, hardware

Can I ask here what are the minimum system requirements to write smart contracts, and do some research on blockchains & cryptocurrency in general?

-For Dell is Vostro, say 3510, enough or I should go for Latitude or Inspiron?

-For Lenovo is IdeaPad 3 enough, or it must be ThinkPad?or Yoga?

-For Asus, VivoBook or must be ZenBook?

-For HP???

I mean I couldn't install docker in my old laptop, because it needs Windows 10 for a start, but there must be other requirements to make it run at ease?

-Is 16GB RAM enough?any min cache size?

(For example I was about to decide Dell Vostro 3510 is adequate then I saw a comment in the comparisons that "If you are not docking...", same worries for other brands )

-Also, I will probably need to do simulations like those papers about EIP-1559; or process the whole Blockchain status, sorry the example I had in mind from Bitcoin any runs on the UTXO set that's 5GB

-NFT research and projects are in my mind too

-If I ever decided to participate in a mining pool, do I need a GPU & what size?
....
I think I should add what I've just noticed necessary for running docker on windows 10 or 11 is to successfully run **WSL 2**, which requires:

64-bit processor with **Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)**
It turned out that not all processors are with SLAT, from
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation

*AMD has supported SLAT through the Rapid Virtualization Indexing (RVI) technology since the introduction of its third-generation Opteron processors (code name Barcelona). Intel's implementation of SLAT, known as Extended Page Table (EPT), was introduced in the Nehalem microarchitecture found in certain Core i7, Core i5, and Core i3 processors*

I take it from what is written that all AMD after 3rd generation is SLAT, while I have to check the exact Intel model number to be sure???

From here
https://www.thetechnobee.com/how-to-enable-virtualization-on-amd-ryzen/
It seems complicated somehow to run Virtualization on AMD Ryzen, not the default at least, and made me ***more confused*** whether I should care more about the Graphics card capabilities or what?

They talk about comparison bet **i7 & Ryzen7**:
"*while the number of cores undoubtedly influences performance, gamers will benefit more from a faster single-core clock speed.*"
Now is **Virtualization** and consequently **docker** related to single processor speed?

About **heat with Virtualization**, they say:
*With virtualization increasing CPU utilization to 70%, “that generates a lot more heat,” says Turner, director of networks and systems at Brandeis. … We’re seeing heat dump into these rooms like never before.”*

I found this too at Berkeley University where the course is offered
https://bce.berkeley.edu/enabling-virtualization-in-your-pc-bios.html
But does not name a processor kind; ie., I can't try all the steps they're saying before I buy the laptop?!

Comment: any computer can do the job.

https://remix.ethereum.org/ if you are able to connect on remix at least :)

Comment: I don't think so, in fact I tried many net cafees a while ago, what's the specifications of yours for example? or ur lab/office/company... to not be personal ... a laptop you did urself ran docker and wrote smart contracts,.... etc on?

Answer (score 1):

16GB of RAM is enough. No you don't need a fast GPU. Smart contract research is done on Ganache, a local (simulated) blockchain that is CPU heavy. It's more important to make sure that your RAM and CPU don't bottleneck each other.

Docker is OPTIONAL for students. If you are planning on using a LOT of docker containers, then I suggest 32GB of RAM and a lot of cores on your CPU.

For reference, I run a 2600X with 32GB of DDR4-3000.

For mining pools, you need multiple GPUs. Sorry bud. Also if remix.ethereum.org crashes on you, it's lights out for your entire project. I literally just use it for code fragments. Migrate to truffle, hardhat, or brownie when you get the chance.

Comment: I'm sorry I took sometime searching before I get back to you, this mean AMD(ex. https://btech.com/en/lenovo-legion-5-laptop-amd-ryzen-5-4600h-15-6-1-tb-265-gb-16gb-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1650ti-4gb-win-10-blk.html) is better for me than Intel (https://btech.com/en/asus-f15-fx516pe-hn001t-laptop-core-i7-11370h-15-6-inch-grey.html)?but then they say it  Rzn5 contains hexa=16, here https://www.windowscentral.com/amd-ryzen-which-processor-best-you  it says max.6?or https://2b.com.eg/en/asus-zenbook-13-oled-ux325ea-kg287t-intelr-coretm-i7-1165g7-16gb-1tb-intelr-iris-xe-graphics-13-3-fhd-win10-grey.html

Comment: Sorry something was wrong in the 2nd link. https://btech.com/en/asus-f15-fx516pe-hn001t-laptop-core-i7-11370h-15-6-inch-grey.html.  which is more suitable?

Comment: That article is outdated. The only reason I'm sporting the 2600X is because it's cheap and I have no problems overclocking it. AMD was also generally cheaper than intel at the time as well. I have generally 2 OSs running at the same time. I have Windows as the primary OS for development/gaming (4 fastest cores) and I throw the other one or two cores + 2GB of RAM at a secure, portable linux VM for my personal files on a large USB stick. (wallets and such) This is so that I never get hacked. TL;DR you don't need the BEST, but focus on your CPU + RAM.

Comment: "Suitable" is the best bang for your buck as you can "technically" run python/JS on any machine. I'm just telling you what to prioritize because I made the mistake of spending too much on a GPU for simulated blockchains.

Comment: This one also https://2b.com.eg/en/asus-zenbook-13-oled-um325uaz-oled007t-amd-ryzentm-7-5700u-16gb-1tb-ssd-amd-radeontm-graphics-13-3-fhd-win10-pine-grey.html, however from this comparison.  https://versus.com/en/amd-ryzen-5-4600h-vs-amd-ryzen-7-5700u, it is better to go for higher frequency per processor; but then the NX security bit to prevent hacking in Ryzen7&Intel i7, and not in Ryz5 I think is important.  https://versus.com/en/amd-ryzen-7-5700u-vs-intel-core-i7-1165g7/nxbit. I couldn't run alchemy by myself here,https://github.com/KaihuaQin/defi-mooc-lab2, so I need docker

Comment: One more thing since u didn't reply yet, is what u r talking about what is called *Trustzone* feature? It doesn't exist in any option  https://versus.com/en/amd-ryzen-7-5700u-vs-intel-core-i7-10750h/trustzone,,,, I may end up with ZenBook Ryzen 7 16GB because all the 3or4 have pros &cons, and the others are ~100$ higher in price. I'm not sure what is the added value for me and if it worths.

Comment: My dude, I am running on 2nd gen ryzen just fine and you are super concerned about whether or not a 5th gen ryzen or a 10th gen intel would be just as good. If I had anything to say, it would be that you should pick 3rd gen ryzen and up because they are literally just as good as most of intel's 9th gen lineup.

Comment: Ironically, Ryzen 7 has the least base processor speed among it's predecessors 1.8 GHz depending on having 8 cores. My worry is there an application, specially if it is docker, that depends on/affected by the base speed of the single processor?

Comment: The ryzen 7 5700U has a base clock of 1.8GHz and boosts up to 4.3GHz. The difference between AMD and Intel's top speeds is that AMD intends for that top speed to be sustained whereas Intel only intends for that top speed to be hit for like 30 seconds or so. When you see that 1.8GHz base speed, that means that it will be doing that AT REST to hit that 15W TDP target. When it needs to, it will hit and maintain that boost clock of 4.3GHz. (and obviously increase the consumption of power)